# how to embed foreign object to svg file?

Tags: html, svg

I have working inline svg with a foreign object, but it does not work if i try to make an svg file and insert to the document. How to use the foreign object correctly in the svg file?

Working inline svg:

```
 <svg width="500" height="300" style="border:1px red solid">
    <foreignobject class="node" x="46" y="22" width="50" height="50">
            <div style="border:1px green solid">Wrapped div in svg.</div>               
    </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

Working iline svg with switch:

```
<svg width="500" height="300" style="border:1px red solid">
    <switch>

        <foreignobject class="node" x="46" y="22" width="50" height="50">
            <div style="border:1px green solid">Wrapped div in svg.</div>               
        </foreignobject>

        <text font-size="10" font-family="Verdana">
          <tspan x="10" y="100">Here is a paragraph that</tspan>
          <tspan x="10" y="120">requires word wrap.</tspan>
        </text> 

    </switch>
</svg>
```

Not working svg in the included file. Where is a mistake? I have tried with and without `requiredExtensions="http://example.com/SVGExtensions/EmbeddedXHTML"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated by IcoMoon.io -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="700px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 700 200">

  <switch>  

    <foreignobject class="node" x="46" y="22" width="200" height="100" requiredExtensions="http://example.com/SVGExtensions/EmbeddedXHTML" >
        <div style="border:1px green solid">I'm a div inside a SVG.</div>                
    </foreignobject>

    <text font-size="10" font-family="Verdana">
      <tspan x="10" y="10">Here is a paragraph that</tspan>
      <tspan x="10" y="20">requires word wrap.</tspan>
    </text>
  </switch>
</svg>
```

Comment: standalone SVG is case sensitive, the correct tag name is foreignObject.

Comment: When inlined in HTML, the browser is using the more permissive HTML rules for parsing. So the the incorrect lower-case `foreignobject` is being accepted.  Standalone SVG files are parsed using the XML parser, and the tag names must have the correct case.

Comment: thanks for the notice